# Mapping Attributes

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-online

I have two customized entities: Product and Quote Product. In Quote Product, I have a lookup that brings the name of the entity Product to Quote Product.

I also have a field named `IPI` in Product and Quote Product. What I wanna do is: In Quote Product, when I select the Product, bring the `IPI` field value to a field in Quote Product.

Is there any way to do it by mapping attributes, or only by javascript and plugins? If so, can you help me how to do it?

Comment: No I don't think you can do this by mapping fields, the best approach is by using JavaScript!!

Answer (score 1):

If youre using CRM 2013 you can use sync Workflow without coding or async workflow for CRM2011.

Depends on your need.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't accomplish it by mapping by the way you describe it. There are however four ways of doing this in CRM 2011 that I can think of.

1. iFrame that retrieves the IPA attribute from the related entity. The advantage of this is that it only refers to the attribute, so it doesn't store the attribute twice in the database which is a good thing.
2. JavaScript. Retrieve the attribute from the parent entity using an onchange-script.
3. Plugin that retrieves the related attribute onsave.
4. Workflow as minohimself pointed out which is easy to setup, but in CRM 2011 you have to wait a few seconds for the asynch-service to do its job.

Good luck which way you choose to solve it :)